# How to extends this class?

Tags: php, oop

Having class Certificate with 2 display methods `dispayAsXML` and `displayAsHtml`.
I want to create 2 new classes `BonusCertificate` and `GuaranteeCertificate` these both has additional properties.

Should I extract an Abstract class which contains these properties and extends from abstract class 3 new class or may I leave this certificate class as it is and extends new classes from it? With new properties and override the `displayAsXML` abd `displayAsHtml` methods in new classes?

```
   class Certificate {
      private $isin;
      private $tradingMarket;
      private $currency;
      private $issuer;
      private $issuingPrice;
      private $currentPrice;
 }
```

Comment: Maybe the magic methods __set and __get is something to watch for, you can manipulate the variable scope by using the __set and __get methods

Comment: maybe can you explain better what do you need to achieve?

Comment: Is your question about auto-refreshing your data? If that's the question, I'd try to renew (new $object) your objects every X seconds with AJAX. (google provides tons of intel about AJAX) If you want to make a price history, and want to store it: use a database, or create an enormous array with the time as a key. How do you want the user to post this documents? Where does your server has to get it? You also might want to add some extra classes and methods. (as an example a document class that tells everything about your documents) If it's about calculating all this ?economic? stuff --> I can't

Answer (score 2):

You make a class abstract if you don't want instances of the class itself to exist. So you can create a Certificate class like this:

```
abstract class Certificate 
{
    protected $isin;
    protected $tradingMarket;
    protected $currency;
    protected $issuer;
    protected $issuingPrice;
    protected $currentPrice;

    abstract public function displayAsXML();
    abstract public function displayAsHtml();
}
```

The variables have to be protected, otherwise the class's decendants can't access them. If that isn't necessary, keep 'em private. The `abstract public function`s have to be overridden by classes that are extending from this base class:

```
class BonusCertificate extends Certificate
{
    protected $bonus;

    public function displayAsXML()
    {
        // Do your thing
    }

    public function displayAsHtml()
    {
        // Do your thing
    }   
}
```

So you'll end up with three classes, the third being GuaranteeCertificate and looking like BonusCertificate.

If you however also need "regular" Certificate instances to exist, simply remove the `abstract` from the class and function definitions, and create the `displayAsXML` and `displayAsHtml` function bodies appropriately in the Certificate class. You can still override those functions in derived classes.

Also try to read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) on this.

Comment: Your first code snippet contains errors: An non-abstract class may not contain abstract methods in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You as to ask yourself if there are going to be instances of Certificate class.  If this is allowed, then don't use abstract.  If it is prevented, then use abstract.

Also rename the class to ICertificate instead of Certificate to show that it is an interface

Comment: An abstract class is *not* an interface, those are two different tools. Abstract classes can have implementations, while interfaces can't. Because of this distinction, there is no need to change / prefix the class name, although it may be a good convention to improve readability of `instanceof` operators. Such a naming convention has however no influence at all on the functionality of PHP. See also: [Interfaces in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) and [Abstraction in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

Comment: Uncle Bob says: *If you prefix your interfaces with I, ask yourself why you want your consumer to know it is an interface. Why is that important to them?* [source](https://twitter.com/#!/unclebobmartin/status/131376415328309249)

Comment: @PelletenCate, I see what you mean.  Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You make a class abstract if it's incomplete and you never want instances of the class itself to exist.

But first of all you define the interface of the Certificate:

```
interface Certificate
{
    public function displayAsXML();
    public function displayAsHtml();
}
```

So you can create a Certificate base class like this:

```
abstract class BaseCertificate implements Certificate
{
    protected $isin;
    protected $tradingMarket;
    protected $currency;
    protected $issuer;
    protected $issuingPrice;
    protected $currentPrice;
}
```

The variables have to be protected, otherwise the class's decendants can't access them (and the abstract class does not make any use of them). If that isn't necessary, keep 'em private (or remove them if they are not used at all). The public function`s defined in the interfacce have to be implemented by classes that are extending from this base class:

```
class BonusCertificate extends BaseCertificate
{
    protected $bonus;

    public function displayAsXML()
    {
        // Do your thing
    }

    public function displayAsHtml()
    {
        // Do your thing
    }   
}
```

So you'll end up with three classes, the third being GuaranteeCertificate and looking like BonusCertificate.

If you however also need "regular" Certificate instances to exist, simply remove the `abstract` from the base class and implement function definitions, then move the `displayAsXML` and `displayAsHtml` function bodies appropriately into Certificate render classes, because the display does not belong to the data domain of the object type itself.

Then add a type property to the Certificate base class so you can differ between different type of certificates.

Also try to read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) on this.